# Debug remote v8-based app using Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, nativescript, v8

First of all I am a complete noob when it comes to the Javascript/Node.js/V8/whatever ecosystem but I have recently became involved in some Nativescript projects and I managed to debug the apps using the chrome dev tools, just by pasting the following url into Chrome (Chromium, actually):

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:40000
```

And then I can start browsing the source code, add breakpoints, etc.; however, I'd love to be able to do this from Firefox, and I know it does have a javascript debugger and web inspector for regular web pages, but I wasn't able to find a similar tool for this sort of thing. I even tried remote debugging and used the same port specified in the url but it didn't work. Is this even possible? Is this exclusive to Chrome/Chromium?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot debug v8-based applications, primarily due to the major differences between the debug protocols.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol The v8 debugger conforms to the Chrome Debugger protocol, which the Firefox runtimes have absolutely no knowledge of.

http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/docs/backend/protocol.md

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit, please? I'm not too well versed on v8 so I can't grasp such differences.